# Find X,Y points in polyshape - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In a poylshape, how can I find all the Y points when X is defined as 0.5 and how to find all the X point when Y is defined as 0.75? (the searched numbers can be changed)

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

P = [0.5 0.5; 1 0.75; 0.5 0.75; 0.8 0.8; 0.25 1; 0 1];
pgon = polyshape(P)
plot(pgon)
```

Comment: When you say points are you referring to the vertices of the polygon or all the points contained within the polygon for a given `X` or `Y`?

Comment: All the points in a polygon would result in a line for a given `X` or `Y` in the other case.

Comment: I mean the extracting the matching X or Y in the P (class 'double')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Logically Indexing a Given Column

One way to get matching pairs is to use logical indexing on a given column and use that to index the complementary column. In the case that the `X` is known we can use that to evaluate which indices in column one are equal to a certain value and then use this indices to obtain the corresponding `Y` values in the second column. The vice-versa case is similar when `Y` is known/given.

```
clc;
P = [0.5 0.5; 1 0.75; 0.5 0.75; 0.8 0.8; 0.25 1; 0 1];
pgon = polyshape(P);
plot(pgon);

%Inputting X-coordinate%
X = 0.5;
Y_Points = P(P(:,1) == X,2);
X_Points = repmat(X,[length(Y_Points) 1]);
disp("X: " + num2str(X));
arrayfun(@(x,y) fprintf("(x,y) -> (%.2f,%.2f)\n",x,y), X_Points,Y_Points);
fprintf("\n")

%Inputting Y-coordinate%
Y = 0.75;
X_Points = P(P(:,2) == Y,1);
Y_Points = repmat(Y,[length(X_Points) 1]);
disp("Y: " + num2str(Y));
arrayfun(@(x,y) fprintf("(x,y) -> (%.2f,%.2f)\n",x,y), X_Points,Y_Points);
```

### Output Results:

> X: 0.5
>  (x,y) -> (0.50,0.50)
>  (x,y) -> (0.50,0.75)
>
> Y: 0.75
>  (x,y) -> (1.00,0.75)
>  (x,y) -> (0.50,0.75)